# Match: Deref and mark operator, why they are not the same?

Tags: rust

Here is modified version of [example of usage Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html):

```
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Hash, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord)]
pub struct InternedString {
    string: Rc<String>,
}

impl InternedString {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(string: &'static str) -> InternedString {
        InternedString {
            string: Rc::new(string.to_owned()),
        }
    }
}

impl Deref for InternedString {
    type Target = str;

    fn deref(&self) -> &str { &self.string }
}


struct DerefExample<T> {
    value: T
}

impl<T> Deref for DerefExample<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = DerefExample { value: 'a' };
    assert_eq!('a', *x);

    match *x {
        'a' => (),
        _ => (),
    };

    let s = InternedString::new("aaa");
    match *s {
        "test" => (),
        _ => (),
    };
}
```

it is not compiled, with error:

```
55 |         "test" => (),
   |         ^^^^^^ expected str, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `str`
   = note:    found type `&'static str`
```

but if I call `deref` method by hands:

```
match s.deref() {
    "test" => (),
    _ => (),
}
```

all compiled without errors, what is difference between `*s` and `s.deref()`, and why for `char` all works fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character literals are of type `char`, while string literals are of type `&'static str`. Note that string literals are always references, while character literals are not references.

`*s` is actually translated to `*(s.deref())`, not to `s.deref()`, when performing a deref coercion, because `deref` returns a reference. Thus, to match an `InternedString` against a string literal, you need to take a reference to `*s`, i.e. you need to write `&*s` instead of `*s`. That works because `*s` yields an lvalue.

Comment: But then actually `Deref` trait overload `&` ?

Comment: No, `Deref` really overloads `*`, but the compiler can insert `*` implicitly if the context requires it. For example, if you write `&s`, the compiler may translate it to `&*s`, which in turn can be translated to `&*(s.deref())` (which simplifies to `s.deref()`).